# uap-parser from git on Amazon EMR

Tags: linux, git, scala, sbt, amazon-emr

Im new to scala and so dont really know how to go about this.
In R all one would need to do to install a git repo is:

```
install_github(...)
```

I need to install https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-scala on an Amazon EMR,this is what I have done so far:

```
// Install Sbt    
sudo yum -y install sbt

//Install git
sudo yum -y install git

// Clone git repo
git clone https://github.com/ua-parser/uap-scala.git

//Go to path where scala files are located
cd uap-scala/src/main/scala/ua/parser

sbt
compile
```

I get the following error:

```
> compile
[info] Compiling 8 Scala sources to /home/hadoop/uap-scala/src/main/scala/ua/parser/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /home/hadoop/uap-scala/src/main/scala/ua/parser/CachingParser.scala:5: object twitter is not a member of package com
[error] import com.twitter.util.LruMap
[error]            ^
[error] /home/hadoop/uap-scala/src/main/scala/ua/parser/CachingParser.scala:8: not found: type LruMap
[error]   lazy val clients = new LruMap[String, Client](size)
[error]                          ^
[error] /home/hadoop/uap-scala/src/main/scala/ua/parser/Parser.scala:5: object yaml is not a member of package org
[error] import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml
[error]            ^
[error] /home/hadoop/uap-scala/src/main/scala/ua/parser/Parser.scala:20: not found: type Yaml
[error]     val yaml = new Yaml(new SafeConstructor)
[error]                    ^
[error] /home/hadoop/uap-scala/src/main/scala/ua/parser/Parser.scala:6: object yaml is not a member of package org
[error] import org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.SafeConstructor
[error]            ^
[error] 5 errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

It looks like a dependency problem.How to install theses dependencies? Please guide on how to resolve this. Is there an example where someone has set this up?

Comment: It would be more helpful if you told me whats wrong rather than giving a negative poll.

Comment: Have you tried following the author's build instructions in the readme? Try `sbt package`.

Comment: I did,yes. sbt package gives the same error.So the obvious solution would be to install the dependencies,but the dependencies are also git repos.